# mysql restarted occasionally

Tags: mysql, percona

At night our mysql server restarted occasionally(innodb engine) and in the log I see following:

```
150921  1:58:44  InnoDB: Page checksum 2064838754 (32bit_calc:  866699801), prior-to-4.0.14-form checksum 400856538
InnoDB:stored checksum 1847129036, prior-to-4.0.14-form stored checksum 42278670
InnoDB: Page lsn 0 3564194321, low 4 bytes of lsn at page end 2315587073
InnoDB: Page number (if stored to page already) 80945,

InnoDB: space id (if created with >= MySQL-4.1.1 and stored already) 0
InnoDB: Page may be an index page where index id is 116
InnoDB: (index "idx_cru_type" of table "fisheyedb"."cru_login_cookie")
150921  1:58:44  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 139799134877440 in file rem0rec.c line 569
 InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
 InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
 InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
 InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
 InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
```

at http://bugs.percona.com/
     key_buffer_size=33554432

Is it possible to reveal what happened and what we should do to avoid this behavior further?

Answer (score 1):

I think that table was corrupted. You can use MySQL repair command:
First backup!
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/rebuilding-tables.html

Comment: As far as I know the mysql database with innodb engine wouldn't start if it had corrupted tables. In our case mysql restarted and stil work up now.